# How to have a bash shell access to a vernemq image through docker?

Tags: docker, mqtt-vernemq

I am new with vernemq. I want to run vernmq image using docker and then start it on my node, in particular i want then to install Openssl in my vernemq image. I am using ubuntu 18.04.
I employ this command: `docker run -it erlio/docker-vernemq`

These two pictures represent the output: [image]

[image]

I am not able to open bash related to my vernemq image as we got when executing: `docker run -it ubuntu`

Could you help me please?

Comment: You want to have bash shell access to your vernemq image ?

Comment: yes please I don't how to get access to bash shell access to your vernemq image.